# How to check if any holiday is included in a time period in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in pandas dataframe, start date and end date.

I want to know if any holiday is included in the time period of each row.

I want to create a new column to show yes or no.

```
id  Start Date  End Date
0   2019-09-27  2019-10-06
1   2019-10-09  2019-10-22
2   2019-05-04  2019-05-15
3   2019-09-18  2019-09-29
```

I know how to check if a specific date is holiday or not

But how can I check the duration of each row?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Date':['2019-09-27', '2019-10-09', '2019-05-04', '2019-09-18'],
'End Date':['2019-10-06', '2019-10-22', '2019-05-15', '2019-09-29']})

# To check if a specific date is a holiday or not 
holidays = calendar().holidays(start = df['Start Date'].min(), end = df['Start Date'].max())
df['Holiday'] = df['Start Date'].isin(holidays)

# This can only check if the start date is a holiday
id  Start Date  Holiday
0   2019-09-27  False
1   2019-10-09  False
2   2019-05-04  False
3   2019-09-18  False

# But how can I check the duration between df['Start Date'] and df['End Date'] of each row?
```

I expect that there is another Boolean column to check 
if each row (id) is including any holiday between the duration of start date and end date

```
id  Start Date  End Date    Holiday
0   2019-09-27  2019-10-06  True
1   2019-10-09  2019-10-22  False
2   2019-05-04  2019-05-15  True
3   2019-09-18  2019-09-29  False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I will do

```
#holidays = calendar().holidays(start = df['Start Date'].min(), end = df['End Date'].max())
l=[any(x<=z and y>=z for z in holidays.tolist()) for x , y in zip(df['Start Date'],df['End Date'])]
[False, True, False, False]
df['Holiday']=l
```

---

Also check [When should I ever want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: Great answer, should be accepted answer if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much faster!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the checking function to each row of the dataframe:

```
df['Holiday'] = df.apply(lambda x:\
                   calendar().holidays(start=x['Start Date'],
                                       end=x['End Date']).size, axis=1)\
  .astype(bool) # Convert the answer to a boolean
#0    False
#1     True
#2    False
#3    False
```